# NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined on Mac A1 Monterey

Tags: mysql, django, macos, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am trying to include mysql into my django and face the error of

```
in <module> version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

I think this might be an error due to the new M1 chip and mac OS system, but I can't figure out how to fix it. (I am using mac Monterey with M1 chip.)

Here is the package version:

```
mysql-connector-python    8.0.29
mysqlclient               2.1.1
mysql  Ver 8.0.29 for macos12.2 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
Python 3.8.9
```

I've read it somewhere about my python needs to be at the homebrew directory, but not sure how to do it.

```
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

I've also seen other solution of using

```
arch -x86_64 brew install mysql
```

It didnt work for me. here is my .zshrc file now

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

and here is my bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: You should be able to use ARM binaries exclusively, but you may need to clean out old lingering x86 ones if you've ported over your OS from an Intel machine. Be sure you've updated Homebrew, and try removing and reinstalling MySQL.

Comment: Have you found the solution ?